# Rate of Decarboxylation of pyridinecarboxylic acids

Tags: organic-chemistry

What would be the rate of decarboxylation between the molecules described as pyridine molecules having $\ce{-COOH}$ group at *ortho*-, *meta*-, and *para*-positions?
In which molecule's decarboxylation would be fast or slow?

[image: 2-pyridinecarboxylic acid]

Put the $\ce{-COOH}$ group each at *ortho*-, *meta*-, and *para*-positions of pyridine to make 3 different molecules, then determine the rates.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the subject?

Comment: I know that a carbanion is formed in decarboxylation mechanism. So the rate depends upon the stability of the carbanion formed. But I can't decide how to judge the stability of carbanions so formed.

Comment: You are dealing with compounds that are both amines and acids. Think zwitterions NOT carbanions. Provide a diagram of your efforts if you have the capability/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rate of decarboxylation of picolinic acid **1** is greater than isonicotinic acid **2**. Zwitterion **4** has been proposed as the intermediate (Ref.1). Note that the electron pair is in the sigma framework. An electrostatic stabilization is proposed that requires that the charges be proximate. A competitive reaction in base (no zwitterion) demonstrated that **1** decarboxylated more than 100 times faster than **2** which was recovered after 20 days. Since nicotinic acid **3** is inexpensive and wasn't studied by the researchers, I suspect that it is stable also.

[image: Decarboxylation of picolinic acid]

---

**References:**

1. G. E. Dunn, Gordon K. J. Lee, Harold Thimm, "Kinetics and Mechanism of Decarboxylation of some Pyridinecarboxylic Acids in Aqueous Solution," *Can. J. Chem.* **1972**, *50(18)*, 3017-3027 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1139/v72-480).

Comment: Why would 2 be better than 3 ? I suspect that carbanion would be better stabilized by inductive effects of nitrogen on 3 ?