# Which of these can undergo decarboxylation reaction readily

Tags: organic-chemistry

> Which of these carboxylic acids can undergo decarboxylation readily?
>
> [image]

According to what I know beta-keto acids undergo decarboxylation easily and readily due to formation of a stable intermediate. So my general answer was option (A) however the answer key states that (A),(B) and (D) are correct. I am not able to understand, based on my current theory what is the reason for (B) and (D) to undergo decarboxylation readily.

Comment: With respect of picolinic acid (D) have a look at this   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammick_reaction

Comment: Why do $\beta$-Ketoacids give decarboxylation reactions readily?

Comment: @SafdarFaisal https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/53879/why-are-beta-ketoacids-better-at-decarboxylation-than-gamma-or-delta

Comment: On the decarboxylation of the picolinic acids: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86718/rate-of-decarboxylation/86747#86747

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have said that  β−ketoacids undergo decarboxylation easily and readily due to formation of a stable intermediate. That intermediate is the carbanion on the alpha carbon. So, any species that can stabilize that carbanion can undergoe decarboxylation easily. In (B), the carbanion formed is stabilized by the double bond beside it so it undergoes decarboxylation easily.

(D) is a special reaction as referenced to in [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86718/rate-of-decarboxylation/86747#86747).

[image]

Comment: The only thing I felt was whether stabilization by double bond is "enough" for formation of carbanion to occur but it probably is. Thanks

Comment: Won't the Aromaticity of the cyclo pentene ring be lossed?